# Retriving xml/html attibute - double and single quote issue

Tags: regex

### Code

I have this regex:

```
data-([a-zA-Z_]+[0-9]*)=[\"']([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)[\"']
```

### Current output

If I have this input:

```
<div data-foo="bar">
```

The matches are:

- data-foo="bar"
- foo
- bar

But if I give this input:

```
<div data-foo="ba'r">
```

Then the matches are:

- data-foo="ba'
- foo
- ba

### Desired output

If I have this input:

```
<div data-foo="ba'r">
```

Then I wont the matches to be:

- data-foo="ba'r"
- foo
- ba'r

Comment: Most web languages have builtin HTML parsers. Resorting to regular expressions is a risky path.

Comment: And if you are creating one, how would you do it if not using regex?

Comment: State machine? Hard-coded rules? (I don't really know. Lexical analysis is beyond my area of expertise.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you can do this with languages that have a pcre support (php, ruby, java...).
An exemple with php syntaxe (with a back reference):

```
$pattern = "~data-([a-zA-Z_]+\d*)=([\"'])(.*?)\2~";
```

But with this approach you have captured a quote that you don't need.

Another way:

```
 $pattern = "~data-([a-zA-Z_]+\d*)=(?|'([^']++)'|\"([^\"]++)\")~";
```

When using the `(?|...|...|...)` feature you allow the regex engine to give the same number for the different capture groups in the alternative. Thus you obtain exactly that you want with no parasite matches.

Comment: This solved a new issue I had with other characters like åäö..
I'm using c++ btw

Comment: With pcre regex, you can use the \p{L} character class to match all the letters of all alphabets that you want (with accented chars too). This can be useful (but not in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Add the desired characters to be looked for also
     [a-zA-Z0-9_\"'] --> notice that I also added " and '

Answer (score 1):

The '\' is for leap the quotes?

Maybe, if you leap both

data-([a-zA-Z_]+[0-9]*)=[\"\']([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)[\"\']

If you need that the content has the quotes, you need to use - \' or \" or \'" into the group between quotes - Of this way you can take other characters together these now.